# UnsatisfiedLinkError - com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple couldn't find "libjpgt.so"

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studios and I am doing this OCR http://swlock.blogspot.com/2016/07/ocr-tesseract-2.html where the image convert to text but everytime I take an image app the will close and got this error. Anyone can guide me to fix this error? Thanks

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple, PID: 2425
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libjpgt.so"
      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
      at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
      at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onPhotoTaken(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:214)
      at com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.onActivityResult(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java:138)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that the *.so files are not in your *.apk file.  Follow the steps in [this stackoverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154462/building-tess-two-into-a-project-using-android-studios-gradle-build).

You can always go to `Build > Analyze APK...` to see if the *.so files are getting added.  Obviously, if they are not in the APK, then there is no reason to attempt to run the app that needs the *.so files.